# Realm LinkingObjects property is not appearing in Realm Explorer

Tags: database, xcode, realm, code-first

I'm fairly new to iOS Development and Realm, with decent experience in code first database building.

I have a one to many relationship between classes **Routine** and **Workout**, where one Routine may contain many different workouts. Here are my classes:

```
class Routine: Object {
    //Properties
    dynamic var id : Int = 0
    dynamic var routineName : String = ""

    //Relationships
    let workouts = LinkingObjects(fromType: Workout.self, property: "routine")

    //Primary Key Declaration
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

---

```
class Workout: Object {
    //Properties
    dynamic var id : Int = 0
    dynamic var workoutName : String = ""

    //Relationships
    let exercises = List<Exercise>()
    dynamic var routine : Routine?

    //Primary Key Declaration
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

Am I doing this right for the desired relationship? When I build this and look in the Realm Browser the property `workouts` in Routine does not appear.

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, the properties should still at least be visible in the Browser. Are you able to confirm from your app's code that exercises and routines are being saved and you can get that information back out of Realm?

Comment: Everything I've messed with so far has been in the browser, haven't tried any operations from the app itself but I can do that in a second to see. Also, just so were clear, the only property that isn't appearing correctly is the LinkingObjects property workouts sampled above.

Answer (score 1):

It's intended behavior. `LinkingObjects` represents zero or more objects that are linked to its owning model object through a property relationship. Also, it is an auto-updating container type. `workouts` is updated automatically when adding new `Workout` object and assign `routine` property.

`LinkingObjects` is treated as "query" than a persisted property internally. When accessing `workouts` property, Realm queries to find `Workout` objects that contain matched `routine` objects. That's why `workouts` property is not shown in Realm Browser.